# Create dataframe column based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with `columns[id, type, income]` and want to add an additional column called `incomebracket` based on income. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Ideally I would create the new `incomebracket` column based on a series of intervals. ie:

```
incomebracket = 1 if 100000 < income < 150000
```

So far I know how to create a blank dataframe column: `df['incomebracket']`, but I can't figure out the rest.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: i've made progress with `df.incb[df.income > 200000] = 1`. With enough of these statements I can accomplish my goal - however I assume there is a better (more efficient? more nerdy?) way, and it would be nice to learn if anyone has a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df['incomebracket'] = 0 #default
df.incomebracket[(df.income >= 100000) & (df.income < 150000)] = 1
```

My preferred way is using numpy where

```
import numpy as np
df['incomebracket'] = np.where((df.income >= 100000) & (df.income < 150000), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"income": np.random.uniform(0, 10**6, 10)})
>>> df["incomebracket"] = pd.cut(df.income, np.linspace(0, 10**6, 11))
>>> df
          income     incomebracket
0  474229.041695  (400000, 500000]
1  128577.241314  (100000, 200000]
2  254345.417166  (200000, 300000]
3  622104.725105  (600000, 700000]
4   93779.964789       (0, 100000]
5  865556.464985  (800000, 900000]
6  304711.799685  (300000, 400000]
7  601910.710932  (600000, 700000]
8  229606.880350  (200000, 300000]
9   49889.911661       (0, 100000]

[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

See also [`pd.qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html).